# Java8 compile error for IntSummaryStatistics

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-stream

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;`
```

I came across this error in Java8 (in Eclipse Oxygen) :

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
IntSummaryStatistics stats2 = nums.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x->x));`

System.out.println(stats2);// Works!
```

Now instead of using stats2, i directly pass the entire RHS to println:

```
System.out.println(nums.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x->x)));// Compile Error
```

> Error: The method println(char) is ambiguous for the type PrintStream

However, if I add a toString(), it works.

```
System.out.println(nums.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x->x)).toString());
```

So I am wondering why it's behaving like this!

Generally when we pass an object to `System.out.println()`, it's `toString()` method would be called (internally). So why do I need to explicitly call the toString() method?

Also usually we can substitute the RHS to another method, like :

```
double x = Math.sqrt(5);
System.out.println(x); // works
System.out.println(Math.sqrt(5)); //RHS substitution works
```

Any help in understanding this would be great.

Added the exact code.

```
package java8.examples;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SampleProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        IntSummaryStatistics stats = nums.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x->x));
        System.out.println(stats);
        System.out.println(nums.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x->x))); //Produces compile error
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your imports

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

Comment: its working without any issue https://ideone.com/v9X7TQ

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @nullpointer: can you take a look at it now. I have added a sample code.

Comment: @justintime there is no compilation error in the shared code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a Eclipse issue. There is a open bug for Eclipse Oxygen warning this ambiguity in a method.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=527083

In your case, a workaround, it would be solved by casting:

```
System.out.println((IntSummaryStatistics)nums.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x->x)));
```